# Vue.JS и YandexMaps. Все балуны должны быть открыты по умолчанию

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yandex-maps-api

Новичок в Vue. Подскажите как сделать все балуны на карте открытыми?

```
    <template>
    <div id="YMap">
        <yandex-map
            :controls="['zoomControl']"
            :coords="[52.267755, 76.985748]"
            zoom="13.5"
            style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;"
        >
            <ymap-marker
                marker-id="1"
                :coords="[52.264168, 76.953924]"
                :options="{ balloonCloseButton: false, balloonMinWidth: 140, hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false, balloonOffset:[110, 160]}"
                :icon="{ layout: 'default#image', imageHref: '/images/station_icon.svg', imageSize: [48, 70], imageOffset: [0, 20]}"
                :balloon-template="balloonTemplate"
                marker-type="placemark"
                cluster-name="1"
            />

            <ymap-marker
                marker-id="2"
                :coords="[52.273383, 76.997612]"
                :options="{ balloonCloseButton: false, balloonMinWidth: 140, hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false, balloonOffset:[110, 160]}"
                :icon="{ layout: 'default#image', imageHref: '/images/station_icon.svg', imageSize: [48, 70], imageOffset: [0, 20]}"
                :balloon-template="balloonTemplate"
                marker-type="placemark"
                cluster-name="1"
            />

        </yandex-map>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        name: "YMap",
        data: function () {
            return {
                toggle: true
            }
        },
        computed: {
            balloonTemplate() {
                return `
                    <div class='body_balloon'>
                        <div class='body_balloon_inner'>
                            <p class='status_title'>Свободно</p>
                            <p class='status'>2/2</p>
                            <p class='work_time_title'>Работает</p>
                            <p class='work_time'>7:00-22:30</p>
                            <a @click='toggle = !toggle'>Подробнее</a>
                            <p v-show='toggle' class='spot_hid_descr'>ASDASDASD</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Насчёт балунов. "Балун — всплывающее облако, которое может отображать любое HTML-содержимое. Обычно балун существует на карте в **единственном** экземпляре" (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Balloon-docpage/ )

Вот тут: https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/24098 пишут, что интерфейс проектировали "с учетом того, что балун на карте один, и открытие нового, закрывает старый".

Возможно, стоит рассмотреть метки со своим HTML макетом вот пример в песочнице: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape
или просто stretchy-метки: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geoobject_contextmenu

Comment: Блин, и правда нельзя =(
Спасибо за ответ!